# Origami couldn't export iOS code (Swipe-away navigation)

Tags: ios, origami

I am trying to export the swipe-away navigation iOS code from the following example but it return only an empty m file. Anything I missed?
http://facebook.github.io/origami/tutorials/

Alex

Comment: Must be a bug, the same happens to me. You can report it on the [official Origami Community facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/origami.community/) if you like. The creators are very active there.

Answer (score 0):

You can only export nodes that belongs to Pop/Rebound library. Swipe, interaction and hit zones are not part of that library.